# Static ADO recordset returns RecordCount -1 when using common table expressions

Tags: sql-server, vba, oledb, ado

According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms676701(v=vs.85).aspx), `Recordset.RecordCount` is supposed to return the actual number of rows when using a static recordset (emphasis mine):

> The RecordCount property will return -1 for a forward-only cursor; **the actual count for a static or keyset cursor**; and either -1 or the actual count for a dynamic cursor, depending on the data source.

However, this is apparently untrue when using the `SQLOLEDB` provider and an SQL statement that includes a common table expression:

```
Const sql1 = "SELECT myField FROM myTable"
Const sql2 = "WITH mycte AS (SELECT myField FROM myTable) SELECT myField FROM myTable"

Dim cn As New ADODB.Connection
cn.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Server=myServer;Initial Catalog=myDatabase;Integrated Security=SSPI"

Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
rs.CursorLocation = adUseServer

rs.Open sql1, cn, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly, adCmdText
Debug.Print rs.RecordCount      ' Yields 156 '
rs.Close

rs.Open sql2, cn, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly, adCmdText
Debug.Print rs.RecordCount      ' Yields -1; should be 156 '
rs.Close

cn.Close
```

**Is this a known issue?**

I am aware that I can work around this issue by using a client-side instead of a (default) server-side cursor, but I'd rather not do that to avoid introducing regressions in our legacy code.

Comment: In `sql2`, are you ignoring (not using) `mycte` intentionally?

Comment: @stakx: Yes, because accessing `mycte` is not required to reproduce the problem (just the declaration suffices), and I wanted to provide a minimal example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the second case, ADO does not create a static cursor. Apparently, the OLE DB Provider does not support server-side static cursors with CTEs and changes the cursor type to `adOpenForwardOnly`. Forward-only cursors always return -1 as the `RecordCount`.

*Credit for discovering this goes to [Dan Guzman](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/14cd65c9-d4f8-4aa7-bd21-999f89bf7924).*